# Branch and bound defining a estimated cost

Tags: algorithms, branch-and-bound

How can I define a valid $\hat{C}$ for a job assignment problem where I have $n$ jobs and always $3$ employees, where the cost of an employee doing a job is defined as $C_{ij}$ and no employee can do more than $\lceil \frac{n}{3} \rceil$.

I know that if I had $n$ employees and $n$ jobs then I can do something like:
$\hat{C}(N) = csf + \sum^{n}_{i=k+1}p_i, p_i \notin columns(N)$ where $p_i$ i the min of a row and $k$ is the level of node $N$, but how could I incorporate the limit on number of jobs per person?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  What do you mean by "How do I define a valid..."?  It seems like you have just defined the criteria under which it is valid.  I am having a hard time understanding what kind of answer you are looking for.  Are you looking for an algorithm to compute something?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to define all notation.  I don't know what $\hat{C}$ is supposed to represent, or what is meant by $C_{ij}$, or "no more than $\lceil n/3 \rceil$" (some words seem missing).  I don't know what is meant by $csf$ or $k$ or $N$ or $columns(N)$ or what are the rows or what is a "nose".  It seems like there is a lot of context that is not specified clearly here.